# Showing loading gif only till certain amount of images are loaded

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, image-preloader

I have a site with a fullscreen background carousel and a loading gif on window load.
The problem is that depending on the site, I have 10 to 40 images in the carousel, which means that the loading gif will be spinning for way too long time.

I'm thinking that would be a good idea to actually display the loading gif only till the first 5 images are loaded. That, plus the 10 seconds that every image is shown, gives enough time for the other images to load.

The problem is that I don't know how to approach this solution. Any thoughts?

Here's my jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = 'img/loading.gif';
//<![CDATA[
  $(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
    $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
    $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow', function(){
      $( "#carousel-example-generic" ).attr('data-ride', "carousel");
    }); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
    $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
  });
//]]>
</script>
```

And a piece of my HTML:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="0">

<div class="carousel-inner">
 <div class="item active">
    <img src="./img/1.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="./img/2.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="./img/3.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="./img/4.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="./img/5.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="./img/6.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="./img/7.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="./img/8.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="./img/9.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="./img/10.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a nice and easy way!

```
<script>  
var numImagesLoaded = 0;
function incrementAndCheckLoading(){
    numImagesLoaded++;
    if(numImagesLoaded == 3){
        //kill loading screen, launch carousel
    }
}    

image1 = new Image();
image1.src = "img/1.jpg"
image1.onload = incrementAndCheckLoading;
image2 = new Image();
image2.src = "img/2.jpg"
image2.onload = incrementAndCheckLoading;
image3 = new Image();
image3.src = "img/3.jpg"
image3.onload = incrementAndCheckLoading;
</script>
```

With this script, the loading screen will disappear when the firsts 3 images are loaded, and because each image displays during an x amount of seconds, the site has time to load the other images on the back.

Thanks to dtech, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580426/creating-a-loading-screen-in-html5).